# subdomain redirection to main site url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, subdomain

I have a site with sub-domain concept, like

```
http://**test**.abc.com/
```

It works fine. But user try some different name instead of **test** like

```
http://**sdfd**.abc.com/
```

It will shows the file structure.
How to solve this.. And how would I redirect the wrong url to my url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `.htaccess` file of subdomain's `DocumentRoot`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=test.abc.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://test.abc.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```